# How can I print a multilevel list based on 2 documents from mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have 2 related documents in mongodb: Departments and Functions. Each Department has a set of Functions. I want to print them in the same route with expressjs.

The Route is this:

```
//==============INDEX ROUTE================
router.get('/departments', function(req, res){
    //Get all departments from database
    Department.find({}).populate("occupations").exec(function(err, allDepartments){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render('departments/index', {departments: allDepartments});
        }
    });
});
```

The models are:

```
var departmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    departmentName: String,
    occupations: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Occupation"
        },
        occupationName: String

    }
});
```

and

```
var occupationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    occupationName: String
});
```

and I want to print on screen like this:

1. Department 1:

   - function 1.
   - function 2.
   - function 3.
2. Department 2:

   - function a.
   - function b.
3. Department 3

   - function x.
   - function y.

Comment: Why do we have occupation name two places

Comment: On Department model this is the way to access the occupation name from occupatiin collection.